# GNU Scientific Library Compilation Error for ARM Cortex M Procssor

Tags: c++, c, gsl, wavelet

I am doing wavelet in C and luckily found GSL-2.1. I am trying to interface GSL-2.1 for ARM Cortex-M processors in Code Composer Studio as well as Energia 15. Code is very simple

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_test.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_wavelet.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_wavelet2d.h>


int i, n=256, nc=20;
double data[256];
double abscoeff[256];
gsl_wavelet *w;
gsl_wavelet_workspace *work;

int main(){
w = gsl_wavelet_alloc (gsl_wavelet_daubechies, 4);
work = gsl_wavelet_workspace_alloc(256);

}
```

Even for this code, compiler is giving following error in Energia 15.

```
error: 'w' does not name a type
error: 'work' does not name a type
```

and Code Composer Studio is showing following error

```
undefined                   first referenced
 symbol                         in file     
---------                   ----------------
gsl_wavelet_alloc           ./main.obj      
gsl_wavelet_daubechies      ./main.obj      
gsl_wavelet_workspace_alloc ./main.obj   

error #10234-D: unresolved symbols remain
```

I already asked it [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/322814/gnu-scientific-library-compilation-error-for-arm-cortex-m-procssor) and tried to do some modification in code. I had to add almost 5 c files to reduce #errors. Now I am getting only one error

```
" RETURN_IF_NULL undef symbol first referenced in ./main.obj "
```

Definitely I need to add one or more .c file here but I am lost. can you help me which file do I need to add here.
Any help would be appciated.

Comment: `RETURN_IF_NULL` sounds like a macro, i.e. there's some header problem.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It is a function called in almost 100 files of GSL-2.1 for freeing the memory or to check whether pointer is not a NULL pointer. sample code is given below

  RETURN_IF_NULL (p);
  free (p->range);
  free (p->sum);
  free (p);

But I could not find the source file.

Comment: I found elsewhere a `return_if_null` in gsl `config.h` but is defined as: `#define RETURN_IF_NULL(x) if (!x) { return ; }`

Comment: I too searched in 'config.h' file but I could not find it. Can you link your 'config.h' file here.

Comment: @terencehill thanks, I have added this part of code in header file and now it is working.

Comment: Happy to know that it's working. Also, I think I understood the problem and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/gsl-ref.html), it seems to me that there is a missing macro (`RETURN_IF_NULL(x) if (!x) { return ; }`) that
should have been created by the **autoconf** tool, using the information in `configure.ac`, and added in the `config.h` file, like in this [config.h](https://github.com/ampl/gsl/blob/master/config.h.in).

In the source code, in the file `configure.ac`, there is a directive:

```
AH_BOTTOM([#define RETURN_IF_NULL(x) if (!x) { return ; }
])
```

which instructs autoconf to add the macro at the end of the file config.h that is created after you run the `./configure` script (tested it on my OSX 10.10, gsl-2.1).

I guess that something went wrong during the configuration. If you already have a config file in the include directory of **gsl** then you can add at the very end:

```
RETURN_IF_NULL(x) if (!x) { return ; }
```

Or you can create it and then include it in your source files.